# oxford MAT 2015 incorrect solution?

Tags: logic

In the Oxford MAT for 2015 question 6 part ii) (link below). Poses the following question:

The world is divided into Vampires (V) and Werewolves (W) who tell the truth when talking about their own species and lie when talking about other species. They know instinctively what other species are and they are all aware of this arrangement.

C says: "D says: "E is V""

what can be inferred about C, D, and E?

The solutions say that we can infer that C is a vampire.

Here is my argument that this is the incorrect solution.

If C is telling the truth.
Then C and D are the same species.
D must be V, since D can only say this if D is V (shown in part i).
So C is also V since C and D are the same species.

If C is lying.
Then C and D are opposite species.
D might not have said anything at all.
so we can infer no information about D.
So all we know is that C is the opposite species of D.

So in total, we can infer that C and D are not both Werewolves and nothing more.

Here is what I think is the solution's mistake.

The solution also rules out C is W and D is V.
It does this by arguing that, if D is V, then D does say that E is V, so C is telling the truth, so C is V.

The problem is that D doesn't necessarily say anything in this case. If D were to comment on the species of E, that is what they would say, but we don't know if this happened or not. So in this case D is V does not imply D says E is V.

The implication is not true both ways.

(D says "E is V" -> D is V) is a tautology,

(D is v -> D says "E is V") is not a tautology

if the statement would have been posed:
C says: "If D were to say what species E is, then D would say: "E is V""
Then the solution would be correct. But it's not.

Am I mistaken here, if so, what have I done wrong?

Comment: https://www.maths.ox.ac.uk/study-here/undergraduate-study/maths-admissions-test

Comment: The official solution is correct: "If the statement about Dita is false, then Cesare and Dita are different species. We can tell
nothing about Elith: for example, maybe Dita says nothing about Elith. ... So Cesare is a vampire"

Comment: I agree with everything you said; the solution is incorrect. I guess they could have fixed this by writing 

C says "if D were asked whether E were a vampire, they would say yes."

Comment: It's a bad question. It's not even clear if C is talking about D, or if C is talking about both D and E